# Unable to Bootcamp mid-2011 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, bootcamp, windows

I have been trying to get Windows running on my MacBook Pro after I deleted linux. I have the disk back to 2 partitions and bootcamp assistant tells me that it is unable to partition the boot volume or restore to a single partition.

Diskutil list gives me:

```
Jamess-MacBook-Pro:~ jamesestes$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       
IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                  Apple_HFS MacBook Pro             397.9 GB   disk0s2
3:                  Apple_HFS Recovery HD             101.8 GB   disk0s4
```

Comment: Recovery is colossal - should be about 650MB. 'Simplest' would be reformat the whole thing & recover from Time Machine, 2nd would be see if [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) can fix it, 3rd would be what will probably be the actual answer… some nasty fiddling in Terminal.

Comment: The recovery partition grew when I deleted my linux partitions. I now have it back to 650MB but there is now free space on my disk.

Comment: My favourite would still be Paragon - all the functionality with none of the heartache [I don't like to put it in answers because people who want finicky Terminal solutions give me grief about it ;-)

Comment: I am unable to get Paragon working.

Comment: because…? You have to bear in mind we cannot see over your shoulder.

Comment: Paragon continues to install system extensions then reboots. After a reboot, it wants to install extensions again and it continues to repeat this process.

Comment: Then I'm back to option 1, reformat the whole thing, recover from Time Machine.

Comment: When paragon goes to reboot are you going in to System Preferences -> Security and Privacy and enabling the extensions?